# How to deselect radio button when another radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is a way where i have i 2 groups of radio button
eg

group 1

```
<input  type="radio" name="things" value="car" />  car
<input  type="radio" name="things" value="car" />pen
<input  type="radio" name="things" value="car" />TV
```

group2

```
<input  type="radio" name="things" value="exam" />  exam 
<input  type="radio" name="things" value="journey" />journey
```

the question is if i select radio button from group2 
Eg exam it should deactivate radio butons car And Tv from group1 and allow only pen radio button active

Answer (score 2):

Modifying your HTML a bit

```
<div id="grp1">
    <input  type="radio" name="things" value="car" />  car
    <input  type="radio" name="things" value="pen" />pen
    <input  type="radio" name="things" value="tv" />TV
</div>

<div id="grp2">    
    <input  type="radio" name="things" value="exam" />  exam
    <input  type="radio" name="things" value="journey" />journey
</div>

$(function(){
    $("#grp2 input:radio[name='things']").change(function(){
        $("#grp1 input:radio[name='things'][value!='pen']").attr("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/JMnS6/)

Comment: hEy Thanks Rahul Your solution really worked.Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[value="exam"]").click(function() {
  $("input[value=\"car\"").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

This should disable the "car" input when the exam radio button is clicked.